# How can I change the default database used for language import in the control panel?

Tags: multilingual

In previous versions of Sitecore (we're on 8.2), when importing a language XML file, the default database for import was master.
In 8.2 the dialogue always opens with the core database selected. Almost all of our imports are for the master database, and messy mistakes have been made.

How can I set the default database for language import to master, to avoid accidentally installing a load of content in core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is not configurable. But I can suggest you few workarounds:

First is changing configuration of Sitecore. Databases list on ImportLanguage form uses `Factory.Instance.Value.GetDatabaseNames()` Sitecore API. This API gets databases from Sitecore configuration. When you open `Sitecore.config` and change order of database nodes `/sitecore/databases/database[id='core']` with `/sitecore/databases/database[id='master']`

Second is more complex:

1. Inherit your new form from `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Globalization.ImportLanguage.ImportLanguageForm, Sitecore.Client`
2. Override `OnLoad` function, fix order. `string[] databaseNames = Factory.GetDatabaseNames();`
3. Open '\sitecore\shell\Applications\Globalization\ImportLanguage\ImportLanguage.xml' and change `CodeBeside` property to use your new class